# Character Truncation Issue

Tags: coldfusion

We are using the tag `cfsavecontent` then publishing to a pdf file. Certain characters seem to truncate the text after those characters.

These are the characters we have seen so far that cause the truncation of text

```
= > < 1
```

We have tried using this expression

```
REReplace(data,'<[^>]*>','','all')

<cfsavecontent variable="Abstract">



</cfsavecontent>
```

Comment: So you are looking to replace certain character with their html equivalent?  ColdFusion has at least two functions that do this, htmlEditFormat() and codeForHtml().

Answer (score 1):

Use `mimetype="text/plain"` with your `cfdocument` to preserve text. `cfdocument` defaults to `text/html` (HTML), which is the reason why characters like `<` and `>` mess with your content.

Alternatively you can encode your content for HTML. There's `htmlEditFormat` (CF9-) and `encodeForHtml` (CF10+) to do so, e.g. `<cfset Abstract = htmlEditFormat(Abstract)>`.